# Get empty array on a bson doc from mongoid for newly initialized parent object

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, embedded-documents

Trying to get my initial object to have an empty array the represents an embedded has many documents that currently has no documents embedded.

I can get the relationship in the json string when it has a doc embedded or after I delete all embedded docs. But before any docs are embedded I do not get the attribute character_classes in the json string.

You can see my models below and below that IRB outputs to show what I get when I use to_json and as_document. The first set I don't get the character_classes both after the add and the delete I do...

The question: how do I get the initial set up to pass character_classes as an empty array?

===========Models==========================

```
class Character
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :character_classes
end

class CharacterClasses
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_in :character_classes

  field :title
  field :character_level
end
```

==========IRB==============================

`> char = Character.first`

`=> #<Character _id: 550a1bd94e696383d1020000, created_at: 2015-03-19     00:44:09 UTC, updated_at: 2015-03-19 00:44:09 UTC>`

`> char.character_classes`

`=> []`

`> char.as_document`

`=> {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('550a1bd94e696383d1020000'), "updated_at"=>2015-03-19 00:44:09 UTC, "created_at"=>2015-03-19 00:44:09 UTC}`

`> char.to_json`

`=> "{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"550a1bd94e696383d1020000\"},\"created_at\":\"2015-03-19T00:44:09.232Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2015-03-19T00:56:01.257Z\"}"`

`> char.character_classes.create(title: "data")`

`=> [#<CharacterClass _id: 550a1d914e69638730000000, title: "data", character_level: 1>]`

`> char.as_document`
 `=>  {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('550a1bd94e696383d1020000'), "updated_at"=>2015-03-19 00:44:09 UTC, "created_at"=>2015-03-19 00:44:09 UTC, "character_classes"=>[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('550a1d914e69638730000000'), "title"=>"data", "character_level"=>1}]}`

`> char.to_json`

`=>"{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"550a1bd94e696383d1020000\"},\"character_classes\":[{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"550a20a74e69638730010000\"},\"character_level\":1,\"title\":\"data\"}],\"created_at\":\"2015-03-19T00:44:09.232Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2015-03-19T00:56:01.257Z\"}"`

`> char.character_classes.destroy_all`

`=> 1`

`> char.character_classes`

`=> []`

`> char.as_document`
 `=> {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('550a1bd94e696383d1020000'), "updated_at"=>2015-03-19 00:44:09 UTC, "created_at"=>2015-03-19 00:44:09 UTC, "character_classes"=>[]}`

`> char.to_json`

`=> "{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"550a1bd94e696383d1020000\"},\"character_classes\":[],\"created_at\":\"2015-03-19T00:44:09.232Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2015-03-19T00:56:01.257Z\"}"`

## Edited

I have realize since having this issue that is has nothing to do with to_json or as_document. The reason it is not getting pulled is because only attributes with values are placed in the database. So when creating a new object, since the embedded docs don't exist yet they are not placed in the database. So when I ask for the record it is just giving attributes that had some sort of value.

For normal attributes I can solve this by making a blank default. But there is no default option on embeds many.

Does anyone know how to initialize the relationship so that is place an empty array into the database?

Comment: It matter because on the other side I am running map (javascript - react) against this attribute and trying hard to not put extra logic in to check if the attribute exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`embeds_in :character_classes` should the `CharacterClasses` class should be `embeds_in :character`. See https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-relations/#embeds-many